# Se puede usar dos action en un form?

Tags: php, html

estoy haciendo un formulario para practicar y nos piden siempre proteger el formulario de inyecciones XXS así :

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

Pero claro, como puedo hacer por ejemplo que si el usuario me mete unos datos correctos y le de a submit le redireccione a principal.php ? Se haria con javascript y luego en el form se pone un onsubmit ?

Comment: Lo que nos comentas no proteje de inyección XXS, puedes poner perfectamente principal.php como destino del form y es ahí (en principal.php) dónde debes usar htmlspecialchars y otras técnicas para evitar el XXS. Piensa que el ataque de inyección XXS se debe a que un usuario mal intencionado, puede poner por ejemplo un código script malicioso en un campo del form y si en principal.php lo muestras tal cual sin procesar y confiando que todo está ok, será ejecutado. Por ejemplo, en un campo de texto puedes poner <script>alert('hacked')</script> pero si usas htmlspecialchars el script no será válido

Comment: entonces en el archivo php de principal.php hago un echo con el htmlspecialchars ?

Comment: Si, eso es, aunque hay que tener en consideración muchas otras cosas, pero eso ya evita muchos de los ataques. Por ejemplo, puedes generar una cadena aleatória en el fichero dónde está el form (desde php), guardarla en una session y postearla junto con el form, luego en el principal.php comprueba que la key es correcta, eso evita otra serie de ataques. También tienes que tener en cuenta ataques SQL injection... la seguridad en las páginas web es todo un mundo.

Comment: Entiendo, si aun me falta otras cosas para comprobar con js y de más. Pero por con el profesor y algunos ejemplos que veia en internet siempre veia que el htmlspecialchars lo ponian en el form, entonces no veia otra forma.

Comment: Pues no se que decirte, en el form no hace falta ponerlo porque el usuario no puede alterarlo (con su entrada de datos me refiero). La regla base de un ataque clásico es "no confies en lo que mete un usuario", por lo que hay que proteger sobre todo esa parte. Evidentemente hay muchos otros vectores, pero eso ya es otra historia... Como ejemplo, prueba a meter esto en una de las webs que haya hecho alguno de tus amigos con usuario y contraseña: ' or '1' = '1

Comment: Si, el truco del 'or'1' = '1 nos lo enseñaron. Pero de momento aun no estamos trabajando con bases de datos. Como hace poco que hemos entrado con php, apenas estamos empezando con formularios, validar log in usando tambien inputs hidden, btoa... Pero me parece interesante lo que dices, no lo sabia.

Comment: pero vaya por lo que recuerdo es que usabamos el htmlspecial en el form por si un usuario desde la url intentaba meter un script volviese a cargar la página y así no dejar enviar el formulario. Al menos por los ejemplos mostrados por el profesor.

Comment: Creo que te confundes, estoy muy seguro que el htmlspecial se usa en la parte que recibe los datos, no en el submit del form y además, se hace exactamente así como explicas, alterando la url.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116703/discussion-between-track3r-and-wail).